# VS Web Essentials Remove Parent Tag

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

In Visual Studio Web Essentials, there's a way to remove a parent tag in html [per the site](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html#tags), but it doesn't give you the shortcut. Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the option under the new lightbulb icon when I place my cursor on the element I want to remove

Comment: Shortcut for that should be Ctrl + "." (i.e. Control Key + Period sign)